# postgres 11: forbid table to be cached

Tags: postgresql, caching, sharding

I have tables `items` and `items_archive`. While items should be "hot" data, items_archive is seldom accessed. How could I tell PostgreSQL never to cache(add to heap) items_archive, so that all heap will be provided to `items`?

Comment: Postgresql doesn't give such granual control over caching.

Comment: If you don't access the archive it will be aged out of the cache quite quickly.

Comment: What do you mean by "heap"?